# Verification of approach for notification email sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, notifications, actionmailer

Every now and again I find myself building a feature and completely doubting whether my approach makes sense or is entirely out of whack. I was hoping somebody might be able to verify my strategy here.

I'm building a system that notifies users via email that certain actions have been taken within the site like comments, posts, etc. I currently have a model called ActionEvent which tracks all of these interactions. Anytime a user posts a comment, for example, a new ActionEvent is created which documents that action (who posted it, what it was posted to, and the context). Ideally, when these action events are created, I would also want to send out a notification by email. There are tons of events that warrant emails, and events frequently cause more than just one person to be notified.

Things get a little hairy at this point, because I don't necessarily want to flood people's inboxes with emails if, say, someone posts three comments in 5 five minutes. So I decided to build an action_event_email model to track all the emails that have been sent, and for what reason. The idea is that before any emails are sent, the system will check the previously sent emails to make sure that no emails of a particular type were sent to a particular user within an acceptable timeframe before delivering the email. Does this make sense, or am I missing something really obvious here? I'm worried that once I build this infrastructure it's going to be rather difficult to modify down the line.

Has anyone done this before? And if so, how did you do it?

Thanks!